# How to span a div 100% of the available width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two sibling divs nested inside a div like:

```
<div class="row filters-box">
    <div class='col-md-1'>
        <div class="title"><label class="filter-title">Filter</label></div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-9'>
        <div class="column-left pull-left">
        ....
```

The first div with class `col-md-1` has a border-right `1px solid black;`.

And the second div `col-md-9` may span two rows based on the number of items inside.

even if I say `<div class="col-md-1" style="height:100%">` It does not span those two rows.

[image]

**How to make sure the border spans across those two rows apart from saying a fixed height of some px?**

Comment: Why not just make `col-md-9` have a left border of `1px solid black`?

Comment: wrap those two rows inside a `div`. Set the `border height` of that `div` to whatever you want to. That's how you wrap it all together in a border.

Comment: @GaryHoliday Thanks you. I just realized how stupid of a question it was.

Answer (score 1):

I would just change the point of view, and add the border from the right side.

```
... {
    border-left: 1p solid black;
}
```

Comment: True that. It was indeed a stupid question to ask. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's basically what @Gary Holiday commented initially. Feel free to give him some credit.

Comment: @ZombieChowder Sure. It would be entirely unethical if I do not.

Comment: @StrugglingCoder I wasn't referring to you haha, never mind. I'm glad you got your answer tho'